# posting to fb from rails app not allowing identical posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api

I have a rails app where when a post gets made it hits the user's facebook feed.  For some reason, if you make two posts from the same user that derive the same exact fb post back to back, it errors out.

It gives the following error:

```
FacebookApiException :: This status update is identical to the last one you posted. Try posting something different, or delete your previous update.
```

Any reason this would be an issue?